# Coordinates of the vectors of the canonical basis with respect to another basis.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I need to write the coordinates of the canonical basis of $\mathbb{R}_{2}[x]$ with respect to the basis $\beta = (x^{2} + 2x + 1, x^{2} - 1, x^{2} - 2x + 1)$.

The canonical basis $\beta' = (1, x, x^{2})$ is presented in a different order as you can see... but that doesn't make a difference.

The first vector of the canonical basis is $(0, 0, 1)$ and I can't write it as a linear combination of the vectors of $\beta$. What am I missing here?

Comment: $\frac{1}{4} (x^2 + 2x +1) - \frac{1}{2} (x^2 -1) + \frac{1}{4} (x^2 - 2x +1) = 1$.

Comment: Ups... Should I delete the thread?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:

For any vector space $V$, the change of basis matrix $P_{\beta'}^\beta$ from a basis $\beta$ to a basis $\beta'$ is also the matrix of the identity map $\:\operatorname{Id}_V :(V,\beta')\longrightarrow (V,\beta)$. Hence,  the coordinates you're looking for are the column vectors of the inverse matrix $P^{-1}$.